# Why and when should I use the children() method?

Tags: jquery

*Why and when should I use the children() method?*

I was wondering why I'd prefer to use the children() method over just calling the object with it's children in a selector. Following a simple example of this, the first being with the children() method and the latter without:

```
$(".hello").children().on("click", function) { // Do something };

$(".hello world").on("click", function) { //Do something };
```

I recently began using JQuery, so forgive me for this beginner question.

Comment: I think you mean `$(".hello > world")`. Or even `$(".hello > .world")`

Comment: Don't think that was the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you're selecting all the children of any element with .hello, regardless of class those children elements have.

```
$(".hello").children().on("click", function) { // Do something };
```

With this following selection, you're selecting all of the children elements that have the .world class.

```
$(".hello world").on("click", function) { //Do something };
```

I also seem to recall there was a performance difference between the two methods you described and using .find() - ill try to dig it up

edit: as @banana stated below - using find() traverses the tree, whereas children() only looks at first-level descendants.

Comment: So, if I would have a poorly structured HTML, I would use the latter one? EDIT: Sorry, but I just don't really get the reason why someone would make for example a div class called 'world' and put in that div another one with class 'world'

Comment: not necessarily - it gives you flexibility to apply the specificity you need to accomplish your task

Comment: response to you comment edit: you wouldn't do that - it makes selection impossible - at least i know I've never done that

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments. At the moment I cannot really think of a real-situation where-in I would use the children() method, but I came to know more about it now. Thanks again.

Comment: you would use it when you're not sure of the classes of the elements and or when you'd want to iterate over the elements

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the jQuery api's website: [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

*"Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well. Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents().
The .children() method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it."*

`.children()` travels 1 level, only direct child nodes, and does not return text nodes. while selecting directly, will work like the `.find()` function and search through the entire descendant element tree.

when and why to use it is totally up to you. do whatever suits you best, the answer to this question would be off topic on stackoverflow as its mainly opinion based.